# What right must a wordpress database user have?

Tags: sql, wordpress

When I install wordpress in my production environment, the wordpress database will be imported from a dump and plugins will be installed manually, by root, so the database user will not need to create tables. Also, some tables should be read-only from this database user (for instance the user table).

It would be great if someone answered this with privs for installation and for running separately.

My guess: select, insert (in some tables), delete (in some tables), update (in some tables)

#### Some questions:

- "create" is only needed during installation and if you install plugins needing separate tables, correct?
- Alter may be needed if a plugin need to update it's tables, correct?
- Are drop ever needed, maybe when you delete a plugin?

Comment: You may have better luck on wordpress.stackexchange.com. Also see this thread from there - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/mysql-database-user-which-privileges-are-needed

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned all needed priviledges except for index.